# Under what conditions does $(I-N)^{-1}$ exist?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, markov-chains, markov-process, operations-research

Given an nxn matrix N and $I=I_n$, under what conditions does $(I-N)^{-1}$ exist?

On one hand $(I-N)(I + N + N^2 + ...) = (I + N + N^2 + ...) - (N + N^2 + ...) = I?$

On the other hand, $(I-N)(I + N + N^2 + ...) = \lim_{m \to \infty} (I-N) \sum_{i=0}^{m} N^i = \lim_{m \to \infty} \sum_{i=0}^{m} (N^i - N^{i+1}) = \lim_{m \to \infty} (I - N^{m+1}) = I - \lim_{m \to \infty} (N^{m+1}) = I?$

I think $I - \lim_{m \to \infty} (N^m) = I$ if (and only if?) the entries of N are between -1 and 1?

Iirc, one of my professors stated it without specifying why it is true in that case if it was true in that case but not true in other cases or why it is true in all cases. This arose in the context of Markov chains which iirc deal with matrices whose entries are between -1 and 1.

So, does $(I-N)^{-1}$ always exist? If so, why? If not, under what conditions?

Comment: If $N$ is a matrix then $I - N$ is invertible unless $1$ is an eigenvalue of $N$. The series $\sum_{k=0}^\infty N^k$ are called Neumann series and converge (for matrices) if all eigenvalues of $N$ (which can be complex values) all lie strictly in the unit circle.

Comment: The most general statement that I can think of is: $(I - N)$ is invertible if and only if $1$ is not an eigenvalue of $N$ (which, in turn, means that $Nv = v \Leftrightarrow v = 0$). Now, for instance, if $||N|| < 1$, then all the eigenvalues of $N$ lie in the unit disk, so that $(1-N)^{-1}$ exists, and in this case it equals $1 + N + N^2 + \ldots$.

Comment: $I-N$ is invertible when $N$ is nilpotent.

Comment: @lhf Might that have something to do with (I - N)'s inverse equaling a finite sum?

Comment: @BCLC, exactly.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Of course $I-N$ is not always invertible. Clearly, if $A$ is a non-invertible function, then $N=I-A$ causes $I-N=I - (I-A) = A$ to be non-invertible.

The thing is that the expression $$(I+N+N^2+\cdots)$$

makes no sense if $N$ is not some special matrix. For example, if $N=I$, what is $I+N+N^2+\dots$? It equals an infinite sum of identity matrices and it does not converge.

There is a lemma which tells you that if the operator norm of $N$ is smaller than one, then $I+N+N^2+\cdots$ converges, and it converges to an inverse of $I-N$, so in that case, $I-N$ is invertible.

Comment: Followup comment: it is necessary and sufficient that the *spectral radius* be smaller than one. This is because, although the spectral radius is not a norm, there exist vector norms which induce operator norms which are arbitrarily close to the spectral radius. So if the spectral radius of $N$ is $1-\varepsilon$ then we can pick an operator norm so that the norm of $N$ is at most $1-\varepsilon/2$. Now all norms on finite dimensional spaces are equivalent, which gives us convergence in whatever norm we like.

Comment: Thanks. Follow-up question: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1280732/if-the-entries-of-an-invertible-matrix-n-are-between-1-and-1-is-its-operator-n

Answer (score 1):

A condition: If $N$ is nilpotent matrix, then there exists $(I - N)^{-1}$.

A nilpotent matrix, for example: an upper triangle matrix with entries on diagonal are $0$.