# If the entries of an invertible matrix N are between -1 and 1, is its operator norm less than 1?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, markov-chains, markov-process, operations-research

For Euclidean norm.

If so, why?

If not, might $(I-N)^{-1}$ exist some other way?

This spins-off from [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1280156/under-what-conditions-does-i-n-1-exist).

Comment: Technically this question is not well-posed as is, because I can pick a vector norm to make the operator norm of $N$ big. (This is not artificial, either: for instance I could take $N$ whose first column has norm $\sqrt{d}$ ($d$ is the dimension), and then the Euclidean operator norm of $N$ would be at least $\sqrt{d}$.) You want to ask about the spectral radius of $N$.

Comment: @Ian Your answer seems to be no so might $(I-N)^{-1}$ still exist?

Comment: The point is that whether $N$ has operator norm less than $1$ depends on the choice of the norm, yet whether $\sum_{n=0}^\infty N^n$ converges doesn't. The latter is really your question, and as I commented in the other thread, it is necessary and sufficient to have the spectral radius be less than $1$.

Comment: @Ian Um, how about Euclidean? Edited question.

Comment: I already answered that in my first comment: if the first column of $N$ is $[1,1,\dots,1]^T$ then the Euclidean operator norm of $N$ will be at least $\sqrt{d} \geq 1$ (since $\| e_1 \|=1$ and $\| Ne_1 \|=\sqrt{d}$).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To your first question, the answer is generally no.

The matrix
$$
N= \frac 23 \pmatrix{1&1\\1&-1}
$$
will have (Euclidean) operator norm $4/3 > 1$.

$(I - N)^{-1}$ will exists if $\rho(N)<1$ ($\rho(N)$ denotes the spectral radius of $N$).  This in turn is true if and only if $\|N\| < 1$ for *some* multiplicative matrix norm $\|\cdot \|$.

Comment: Is your sample matrix supposed to be N? It is not invertible

Comment: @BCLC missed that part! It's an easy fix, though

Comment: Okay thanks Omn...!