# If $||A^N|| < 1$, is $I-A$ invertible?

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, banach-spaces, normed-spaces

i have been given this question in functional analysis saying:

> Let $X$ be a banach space and $A$ is a bounded linear operator on $X$, and there exists some natural $N$ for which $ ||A^N|| < 1 $. Is $I-A$ invertible?

We need to prove or give a counterexample.

i know it is true when $N=1$ as we proved it in class but for general $N$ i don't know.  help appreciated

Comment: Hints: You have enough knowledge from class to know that $I-A^{N}$ is invertible, and $I - A^{N}= (I-A) ( I + A + A^{2} +  \ldots + A^{N-2} + A^{N-1})$

Comment: @GeoffRobinson thanks but i know not a theorem stating that if product is invertible so are all terms why is what you said enough?

Comment: Even without using the identity that Geoff appeals to which makes this a one-liner, it's not hard to show directly as in the $N=1$ case that the series $\sum_{n\ge 0} A^n$ is norm-convergent.  For instance when $N=2$ you just need separate estimates for odd and even terms.

Comment: [I guess](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1280156/under-what-conditions-does-i-n-1-exist#comment2599408_1280156)

Comment: @GeoffRobinson : You can have $XY=I$ without $Y$ being invertible because $Y$ may not be surjective. Your opertors also commute.

Comment: @TrialAndError: Thanks, yes, you are right. In general, if $XY$ is (both right and left) invertible, then $X$ has a right inverse, and $Y$ has a left inverse.

Comment: But, as you say, my argument above is correct, as all relevant operators commute.

Comment: Can anyone here possible help on my related question? It was posted but still no help on it yet

Comment: But the related question, if I am looking at the right one, already has an accepted answer, which is correct.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The comment by [Geoff Robinson](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1444708/if-an-1-is-i-a-invertible#comment2942796_1444708) was really an answer:

> You have enough knowledge from class to know that $I-A^{N}$ is invertible, and $$I - A^{N}= (I-A) ( I + A + A^{2} +  \ldots + A^{N-2} + A^{N-1})$$